# All created files on a NTFS partition with User Mapping defaults to root owner

Tags: 13.10, mount, permissions, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I've just migrated to Ubuntu from another distribution, and where previously my NTFS partitions worked with the addition of a User Mapping file, now all the newly created files will have the owner set to root, but otherwise everything works as expected.

I've created the user mapping file as described at [this page](https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/user-mapping/). I also tried to remount the partition with both ‘permissions’ and ‘inherit’ parameters, without success. (I have a feeling, that not the proper NTFS driver is used for this.)

What I would like to achieve here is a similar functionality what I have on Windows.
This is an external USB hard drive, and so I would like to avoid adding an entry in fstab if possible.

Why can this happen, and how it can be solved temporally/permanently?